# Can I have multiple SSH keys for the same host and user?

Tags: ssh

I have two accounts on Bitbucket and an SSH key for each one. This is how my `~/.ssh/config` looks like:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket/account1

Host bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdenfityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket/account2
```

The problem is that the SSH agent seems to be unable to deal with two keys for the same host at the same time and I have to remove one of them to be able to use the other one.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the looks of it, Bitbucket has a wildcard DNS entry in place; any random subdomain (`*.bitbucket.org`) will resolve to the same server(s) as `bitbucket.org`.

```
$ host bitbucket.org
bitbucket.org has address 207.223.240.182
bitbucket.org has address 207.223.240.181
$ host random.bitbucket.org
bitbucket.org has address 207.223.240.182
bitbucket.org has address 207.223.240.181
$ host clearlynotasubdomain.bitbucket.org
bitbucket.org has address 207.223.240.182
bitbucket.org has address 207.223.240.181
```

Because of this, you can setup different entries in your `~/.ssh/config` with different hostnames:

```
Host project1.bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket/account1

Host project2.bitbucket.org
 User git
 IdenfityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket/account2
```

In fact, I'd venture a guess that Bitbucket has this wildcard inplace for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 8):

You can create two separate SSH aliases, i.e.

```
Host bitbucket1
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket/account1

Host bitbucket2
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket/account2
```

As long as your IdentityFile's are not the default ones (see [my question here](https://superuser.com/questions/570356/how-to-override-ssh-default-identity)), then you can use these aliases to select which account to connect to.

Comment: This is a better, more general ssh-native friendly solution than Rain's answer. Rain's answer works only because of how bitbucket's DNS is configured.

Note that with eldering's answer, you simply type `ssh bitbucket1` or `ssh bitbucket2` to connect. The Hostname setting in your `.ssh/config` handles the hostname for you.

Comment: @DougHarris I agree; I was unaware of this feature.

Comment: So, you try `ssh bitbucket1`, and if it fails, you try it again?  Or then immediately try `ssh bitbucket2` to see if that connects?  This answer seems like it would more problems/ambiguity than the answer by @Rain.

Comment: @killermist: No, you use `ssh bitbucket1` to connect to account1 (and vice versa for account2). Bitbucket determines your account from the SSH key you use to connect. The point is that the line `Host X` determines a host *alias*, which need not be a real hostname; that is specified by `Hostname` within the entry.

Comment: @DougHarris actually Rain's answer has the advantage that it can be applied to git submodules too. This answer does not work in that case, unless you assume that all the devs in the team will set up the exact same aliases on their machine.