# How can I force SSH to ignore the IdentityFile listed in "Host *" for one specific host?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

My SSH config file is set up to use a specific IdentityFile in the `Host *` section as the default key. For one particular host, I want to offer a different key (and only that key, never the default key).

My ~/.ssh/config file looks like this:

```
Host specialhost
HostName specialhostname.mydomain.com
IdentityFile %d/.ssh/special-key
LogLevel debug
IdentitiesOnly yes 

Host *
IdentityFile %d/.ssh/regular-key
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Regardless of what I do, or regardless of the order of sections in the config file, my SSH client (OS X OpenSSH_6.2p2) offers the 'regular-key' first (which the server accepts, which is not what I wanted).

The ssh_config man page states the following about `IdentityFile`:

> It is possible to have multiple identity files specified in
>   configuration files; all these identities will be tried in sequence.

The "sequence" it refers to is unclear to me, since the IdentityFile listed in the `Host *` section is always offered first, even if "specialhost" is listed prior to it (as in the example above). The `IdentitiesOnly` trick suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/570356/how-to-override-ssh-default-identity) only seems to be relevant to keys offered by ssh-agent. A few [other](https://serverfault.com/questions/450796/how-could-i-stop-ssh-offering-a-wrong-key/450807) similar [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/268776/how-do-i-configure-ssh-so-it-dosent-try-all-the-identity-files-automatically) have not yielded any answers.

I want to leave the regular-key in the `Host *` section because I use that key with dozens of other hosts and I don't want to duplicate the `IdentityFile` in every host entry.

Is there any way to force SSH to offer only the 'special-key' **using just the SSH config** (and without copying my IdentityFile directives to every other host)? I can see how I might achieve this by taking the keys out of the `Host *` section, adding them to the agent, and then using `IdentitiesOnly yes` for specialhost, but I would really prefer to avoid using ssh-agent unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A `Host` line can have more than one pattern. And it's not really spelled out in the documentation, but a "!" (exclamation) at the beginning of a pattern means "apply this section to hosts that *don't* match the pattern". In other words, you can do this:

```
Host * !special1 !special2
IdentityFile etc...
```

And it should match any host except "special1" and "special2".

I don't think the order of the patterns is important. The hostname being checked has to match one non-exclamation pattern, and it has to not match any exclamation patterns.

Comment: A little clarification: you much specify a hostname to exclude. If you use an alias with a `Host` set, the alias won't work as an exclusion.

Comment: This did it. My ssh client was matching `Host *` in all cases, and always picking it's IdentityFile regardless of what I tried. Note: you can also match a wildcard, if needed, e.g.: `Host * !*.example.com`

Comment: This is not really sustainable with a growing list of specialized hosts, but it seems there is no better option...