# Breaking infinite recursion in ProxyJump setting for wildcard host settings

Tags: ssh, openssh

I would like to have all my SSH connections to my corporate network go through a particular jump host:

```
Host *.initech.biz
    ProxyJump conclusions.initech.biz
```

This accidentally causes SSH to try to jump to `conclusions.initech.biz` infinitely.

How can I break this recursion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
Host *.initech.biz !conclusions.initech.biz
    ProxyJump conclusions.initech.biz
```

This matches "*.initech.biz" except for "conclusions.initech.biz".

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/859719/54530).

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. It is shorter and it doesn't rely on the fact that `ProxyJump none` is technically undocumented.

Answer (score 10):

I think this works:

```
Host conclusions.initech.biz
    ProxyJump none

Host *.initech.biz
    ProxyJump conclusions.initech.biz
```

Settings for hosts that appear earlier in the file override those that come later.

The `ssh_config` documentation does not explicitly mention that `none` is valid value for `ProxyJump`, but it does appear to work on macOS 11.2.3 `ssh`, which is OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3.

Comment: You can also use `ProxyCommand none` on any system where `ProxyJump none` doesn't work (if there are any).